# How would I create a Ubuntu Live USB drive to work on a Mac?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, boot, livecd

My friend's Mac is pretty much gone and I want to boot into Ubuntu to try and get some info off before I re-install Mac OS X.

I heard that you need something called rEFIt to boot Ubuntu on Mac hardware but how would I use that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use UNetbootin for mac ( http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ ) and create a bootable usb key from your friend's mac.
But, I saw that you can't boot a usb key with ubuntu on a mac. It has to contain mac os X to boot.
You still can try, and i'm interested in the result. Could you report?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the instruction you can follow:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick

It's seem complicated and needed a working OS X.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called **Linux USB Creator for Mac**. The program will allow you to download the necessary ISO, carry out any necessary formatting, copy the ISO and install the bootloader. Boot up your mac while holding the “alt” key and select the drive corresponding to your usb stick.

More info:

http://penguintosh.com/tag/linux-usb-creator/